# Communicating with a USB device

Tags: c++, usb

I am writing a software that's supposed to use a USB device. I have some problems with the device source code (it is massive and complicated and I only need to access 3-4 specific functions. So I figured that if I know the exact format the commands are written to the USB I can try and read/write directly from/to the USB devise.

How do I do it?

Do write to the driver? do I write directly to the USB port somehow? can anyone please refer me to some simple documents?

The device is identified as HID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try libusb:

http://www.libusb.org/

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki

to work with usb from userspace